# Photodiode not working in reverse bias

Tags: photodiode, optoelectronics, optics, optical-fibre

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm using a photodiode module, model: coaxial InGaAs, Gtel.

I set it in reverse bias with 5V and tested it with a laser but it doesn't give any output voltage. Unfortunately I don't know the laser wavelength. The resistor in this circuit is 5k.

I have 3 of these modules but none of them worked.

Comment: Can you see the laser? If you can see the laser then it is below 700nm and your photodiode can only see 900-1650nm.

Comment: Try it with 2LED's.  One as an LED emitter and 1 used as a Photo diode.  See if you can get that to work.  Allow 1~10uA leakage.

Comment: Find a laser with emission above 900nm and test again.

Comment: @DKNguyen No, I'm sending laser through optical fiber. I will check it.

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 sorry I have not got your idea. Could tell me more   simple?

Comment: Drive LED with slow pulse current. Then use same LED in reverse as a detector and bias like your diode with 1M to GND.  Then in close range observe the voltage with 10M Probe or Logic input device on the output.

Answer (score 1):

In reverse biasing the current will be very small (single uA to hundrets of uA level, it means tenth of mV on 5k), additionally - if you are out of optimal wave length, the sensitivity can be much less than shown in datasheet. Probably this is the reason that you can't see any output. So: try to increase RL to 50...100k or more (500k).

Comment: I will check it and give you feedback.

Answer (score 0):

> I set it in reverse bias with 5V and tested it with a laser but it doesn't give any output voltage.

Photodiodes are current devices, they are to be used with transimpedance amplifiers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier), which translate current into voltage, which could be measured with eg. oscilloscope.

Comment: With a transimpedance amp they are faster and more linear, but they work ok with a resistive load.